# SQL - UPDATE duplo com where duplo

Tags: mysql, sql

Seguinte, é possível fazer dois `update-where` juntos na mesma consulta? Vou explicar, o que queria fazer é o seguinte:

```
UPDATE usuarios
   SET nome = "Matheus Silva"
 WHERE id = 1
   AND UPDATE usuarios SET nome = "Lucas Silva"
 WHERE id = 2;
```

Mas infelizmente não funciona, alguém sabe a forma correta de se fazer?

Comment: Não se junta 2 updates dessa forma. Separe os updates em querys diferentes.

Comment: Mas não há nenhuma forma de juntar dois updates em apenas uma consulta não?

Comment: Dê uma olhada em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178169/sql-multiple-sets-in-one-update

Comment: Eu dei uma olhadinha no link mas infelizmente não resolve meu problema :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possível é, mas a *sintax* é terrível e eu nem recomendaria :

```
UPDATE usuarios SET nome = (
    CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'Matheus Silva'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Lucas Silva'
    END)
WHERE
    id IN (1,2);
```

Imagine gerenciar esse tipo de `query`.
O ideal seria fazer `querys` separadas por `;` como o [@Hoppy respondeu.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108815/sql-update-duplo-com-where-duplo#answer-108817)

```
$query = "
    UPDATE usuarios SET nome='Matheus Silva' WHERE id=1;
    UPDATE usuarios SET nome='Lucas Silva' WHERE id=2;
";
$mysqli->multi_query($query);
```

#### OBS

O MySql tem um opção especifica para este tipo de execução que é o [`multi_query`,](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) que permite a execução de varias `querys` na mesma `string`, caso seja usado o tradicional `query` apenas a primeira sera executada.
Dica @Bacco

Ou enviar dois processos para o banco.

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome='Matheus Silva' WHERE id=1;"
$this->execute($query);
$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome='Lucas Silva' WHERE id=2;";
$this->execute($query);
```

Comment: +1, ainda mais pelo exemplo inicial. Se quiser incrementar, pode avisar que 2 statements na mesma query só funcionam se habilitar o multiple statements antes (por default só executa a primeira). Assim o 1o exemplo com execute fica completinho. O mysqli tem um tratamento especial pra isso, aí não precisa habilitar flag nenhuma: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, Bom eu resolvi optar por fazer do modo tradicional que é duas consultas mesmo rsrs.

Comment: @Bacco, estou lendo sobre isso, aqui por padrão ja é assim então tenho que entender melhor para complementar :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert tranquilo, só quis mencionar pra evitar "efeitos colaterais" se alguém for testar. Isso é uma medida de segurança que foi adotada pra evitar maiores danos no caso de um injection bem sucedido. Mesmo injetada uma 2a query, ela não será executada por padrão. Se o usuário mudar a flag de multiple statements, abre possibilidade de ataque (a não ser que resete ela). Por outro lado o multiple do mysqli apenas quando realmente necessário a superficie de ataque diminui significativamente. **Nota:** nem sempre esta proteção está ativa, depende de versão e configuração.

Comment: @Bacco Pensei nisso enquanto estava lendo, realmente utilizando apenas `query`, seria o ideal.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert ótima resposta, não cogitei de usar case, considero isso uma gambiarra violenta. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome="Matheus Silva" WHERE id=1; UPDATE usuarios SET nome="Lucas Silva" WHERE id=2;";
```

Não sei em qual linguagem está utilizando.. mas tente dessa forma, separando as consultas com ;

Comment: Pelo que entendi, precisa ser numa consulta de update só, tem a clausura where...in para fazer algo parecido.

Comment: Infelizmente já tentei desta forma mas também não funciona, Eu precisava fazer dois update com dois wheres... tô começando achar que não é possível fazer isso em uma mesma consulta :(

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado pela atenção e vontade de ajudar de vocês, De uma certa forma já contribuiu bastante.